# UIScrollView slow frame rate when scrolling, why?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, frame-rate

In my scroll view I have about 20 UIViews each one with a label and button and whenever I scroll, the scroll view lags. Why is this? Could it be because I sub classed the UIViews in my scroll view? Would it be better to just create the UIViews in my view controller?

Comment: load data asynchronously...Use GCD to load data

Comment: can you post your code? how you managed uiviews in scrollview? so that modification can be done.

Comment: Post some code, so we can see it...

Answer (score 0):

You are giving nowhere near enough information for anyone to be able to answer specifically (like, you're giving no information at all). But there's no need to guess. Use Instruments and find out what's causing the problem. Also, for some extremely helpful general principles, as well some techniques for debugging slow scrolling with Instruments, do watch the WWDC 2012 videos on this topic, such as Session 238 - iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading data synchronously into the cells?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, still kind of a beginner, can you elaborate?